# When i change my nginx proxy_pass settings my react app not load

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I have react app node js backend and nginx. I have already get certificate and install it by Certbot.

My application making get and post request, but for it i need to setup proxy_pass settings.

My server block file:

```
server {

        root /var/www/nikolsoborsocial/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name nikolsoborsocial nikolsoborsocial.org
                                     www.nikolsoborsocial.org;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                               
        }
        
        


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nikolsoborsocial.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nikolsoborsocial.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.nikolsoborsocial.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = nikolsoborsocial.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name nikolsoborsocial nikolsoborsocial.org
                                     www.nikolsoborsocial.org;

        
        return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Whera i need to add proxy_pass settings?

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
include proxy_params;
```

If i put it into 433 server location, insted of `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` my react app not load and i got `Cannot GET /` error in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You set up nginx configuration file to serve react file in server block which is 'location /'.

So if you try to add proxy_pass setting in 'location /' block, it overrides the code that serves react files. And Nginx will proxy the request to the backend server running on **localhost:3000**.

***How to resolve this issue?***

You have to serve files to this request in backend server, or add new location block.

here is an example to add new location block

```
server {
    root /var/www/nikolsoborsocial/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name nikolsoborsocial nikolsoborsocial.org www.nikolsoborsocial.org;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # Proxy Pass settings
    location /app {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    # SSL configuration
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nikolsoborsocial.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nikolsoborsocial.org/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so match - i add "api" prefix to all my get urls, as you advise... Now all working!

Comment: Now i have one more small issue: if i try to refrash page with https://nikolsoborsocial.org/help - /help in the end i got 404 Not Found 

Need additional ajustments...

Answer (score 0):

I change my config file:

```
    server {

    root /var/www/nikolsoborsocial/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name nikolsoborsocial nikolsoborsocial.org
    www.nikolsoborsocial.org;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        # include proxy_params;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nikolsoborsocial.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nikolsoborsocial.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.nikolsoborsocial.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        if ($host = nikolsoborsocial.org) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot


            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            server_name nikolsoborsocial nikolsoborsocial.org
            www.nikolsoborsocial.org;


            return 404; # managed by Certbot

        }
```

Thank you for direction @ACS

> location /api/  - resolve my issue!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).